# In UWP input events, what is IsInContact when PointerDeviceType = Touch

Tags: input, uwp

I was wondering if the property `IsInContact` is always true when I'm doing touch interactions (When `PointerDeviceType = Touch`)?

Can there be some sense of "hover" gestures with touch where the `IsInContact` equals true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that property is basically for pen interactions. There is no "hover" support for touch.